# Error finalize the purchase

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

good morning !
I have a problem in my store. When the client will complete the purchase and choose the shipping method , the action is not completed. The Pagania of a small loaded and no longer does anything . In the default theme it works normal. Already looked at the console and does not have any error in JS ...
Someone ?

This are the Errors (added from comments)

```
2015-01-06T11:23:09+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(LogPagSeguro.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/storage/8/7b/b4/arcanusmarket1/public_html/store/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-01-06T11:23:09+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'LogPagSeguro.php' for inclusion
 (include_path='/home/storage/8/7b/b4/arcanusmarket1/public_html/store/app/code/l‌​ocal:/home/storage/8/7b/b4/arcanusmarket1/public_html/store/app/code/community:/h‌​ome/storage/8/7b/b4/arcanusmarket1/public_html/store/app/code/core:/home/storage/‌​8/7b/b4/arcanusmarket1/public_html/store/lib:.:/usr/share/pear') 
in /home/storage/8/7b/b4/arcanusmarket1/public_html/store/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2015-01-06T11:23:09+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(LogPagSeguro.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/storage/8/7b/b4/arcanusmarket1/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/f‌​unctions.php on line 68
```

Comment: any php errors or similar in the logs on the server?
Magento logs, webserver logs...
Is it a purchased theme, or a self build one? can you maybe share the url? Or look in the responses of the ajax requests.

Comment: 2015-01-06T11:23:09+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(LogPagSeguro.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/storage/8/7b/b4/arcanusmarket1/public_html/store/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Comment: 2015-01-06T11:23:09+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'LogPagSeguro.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/storage/8/7b/b4/arcanusmarket1/public_html/store/app/code/local:/home/storage/8/7b/b4/arcanusmarket1/public_html/store/app/code/community:/home/storage/8/7b/b4/arcanusmarket1/public_html/store/app/code/core:/home/storage/8/7b/b4/arcanusmarket1/public_html/store/lib:.:/usr/share/pear')  in /home/storage/8/7b/b4/arcanusmarket1/public_html/store/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Comment: 2015-01-06T11:23:09+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(LogPagSeguro.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/storage/8/7b/b4/arcanusmarket1/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 68

Comment: This errors... :(

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried to upgrade the [PagSeguro](https://github.com/pagseguro/magento) extension to the newest Version?

I've had once a similar issue with a paid extension and the problem was that it tried to load a file named in camel case like `LogPagSeguro.php` but after checking on the filesystem it wasn't written in camel case. So in my case it was something similar to `Logpagseguro.php`.

Maybe check if the file exists in `/lib/PagSeguroLibrary/log` and if it is written correctly.

Otherwise try to upgrade the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try my PagSeguro extension. I guess its more popular and up to date.

http://r-martins.github.io/PagSeguro-Magento-Transparente/